# How to make_shared count times, with different areas allocated without recur to a loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

**How to `make_shared` count times, with different areas allocated without recur to a loop?**

I have the following code:

```
for( unsigned int count = 0; count < demandedSize; ++count  )
{   
   m_connectionList.push_back( std::make_shared< Foo >( m_ip, m_port )); 
}
```

How to shorten this **without a loop**?

I know `std::vector` receaves a second argument as `const T&`, but in that case all `shared_ptr`s points to the same address (value is copied).

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Foo> > vet( demandedSize, std::make_shared<Foo>( m_ip, m_port ) );
```

How to execute `make_shared` count times, with different areas allocated as result without recur to a loop

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? Just use the first code.

Comment: This could also be done with recursion, but that would literally be the dumbest possible way to do it.

Comment: There *will* be a loop anyway, either in your code or in the vector constructor.

Comment: Any solution will involve a loop, rather it's plainly visible or hidden within the solution's mechanisms.

Comment: @François not necessarily, the compiler may choose to unroll the loop if it is short enough.

Comment: @Pubby just for the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class X>
struct arrow_helper_t {
  X x;
  auto operator->()&& { return std::addressof(x); }
};
template<class X>
arrow_helper_t<X> arrow_helper(X&& x){ return {std::forward<X>(x)}; }

template<class F>
struct generator_iterator_t {
  std::size_t i = 0;
  F f;
  generator_iterator_t()=default;
  generator_iterator_t(generator_iterator_t const&)=default;
  generator_iterator_t(generator_iterator_t &&)=default;
  generator_iterator_t& operator=(generator_iterator_t const&)=default;
  generator_iterator_t& operator=(generator_iterator_t &&)=default;
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
  using reference=decltype(std::declval<F const&>()(std::declval<std::size_t const&>()));
  using value_type = std::decay_t<reference>;
  using pointer = arrow_helper_t<reference>;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using self_t = generator_iterator_t;
  friend bool operator!=(self_t const& lhs, self_t const& rhs) { return lhs.i != rhs.i; }
  friend bool operator==(self_t const& lhs, self_t const& rhs) { return lhs.i == rhs.i; }
  decltype(auto) operator*()const { return f(i); }
  auto operator->() const { return arrow_helper(**this); }
  self_t& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
  self_t operator++(int) { auto r = *this; ++i; return r; }
};
template<class F>
generator_iterator_t<F>
generator_iterator( F f, std::size_t i ) {
  return {i, std::move(f)};
}
template<class F>
auto generator_range( F f, std::size_t i ) {
  return std::make_pair(
    generator_iterator(f, 0),
    generator_iterator(f, i)
  );
}

auto range = generator_range([&](auto){return std::make_shared< Foo >( m_ip, m_port );}, demandedSize);
m_connectionList.reserve( m_connectionList.size()+demandedSize );
m_connectionList.insert(m_connectionList.end(),
  range.first, range.second
);
```

or somesuch.  `boost` probably does it better.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f592ac3e64340921).

Comment: [boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/generator_iterator.htm)

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
std::generate_n( back_inserter( m_connectionList ), demandedSize, [this]{
    return std::make_shared< Foo >( m_ip, m_port ) );
});
```

[Live Example on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/861f9d2da1437b0d)

Comment: Although this indeed does it via a visible loop - the first version in the question is so much more readable.

Comment: @erenon Unfortunately it's only 8 characters shorter than OPs code, but there might be a few other advantages: no explicit loop counter variable (less variables = less state to worry about), less logic where the writer of the code or future maintainers could make mistakes. Also useful in a more generic context (e. g. template function).